# How to use ECSCredentials with AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

I have a react application that is being run on an ECS container. I am trying to provide AWS credentials via the ECS container so that I can make calls to other AWS services from within the application.

This is what I have currently tried:

```
const chain = new AWS.CredentialProviderChain();
chain.providers.push(new AWS.ECSCredentials());
const secretsmanager = new AWS.SecretsManager({
   region: 'us-east-2',
   credentialProvider: chain,
});
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

`ECSCredentials is not a constructor`

I have also tried not including the `ECSCredentials` directly, but then I get an error stating that there are missing credentials in the config.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and why it is saying that this is not a constructor? I have followed the SDK documentation as best as I can tell.

Comment: check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECSCredentials.html), You might have to pass additional details in `ECSCredentials({})`.